# refreshcontrol on nested table not working (ios development)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to get "swipe to refresh" working on my project but for some reason it just won't...

As far as I know it should be pretty simple

1. Write the action listener.
2. Instantiate refreshControl in viewDidLoad.
3. Add it to the tableView of choice.

and that's what i've done but it's not working.

The controller in which I'm writing the code extends UIViewController and holds a scrollview which, in turn, holds a tableview. So:
view => scrollview => tableview

It's on that inner tableview that I want to place the refreshController.

Here are some relevant code snippets of what I've got so far. In the UIViewcontroller's "viewDidLoad"

```
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Pull to Refresh"];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(refresh:)
                    forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.tableCommunity addSubview:self.refreshControl];
```

and the refresh method:

```
-(void)refresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refreshControl {
    [self loadOrganizationswithOffset:0 andLimit:item_load_limit andInviteStatus:invite_accepted];
}
```

The method that gets called there will generate a network call to update the data, when the response returns `[self.refreshControl endRefreshing];` gets called

And that's about it, the rest works fine. Data gets loaded in from the network and displayed correctly, it's only the swipe to refresh part that doesn't.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright, seems like i found an answer. As I expected it had to do with the way my views are build.
On the main page I have 1 scrollview with paging enabled, to which I add 3 "child" pages (tableviews) that each show a different set of data.
So in order to have a working refresh control I need to add a new one to each tableview  and not the same one to all three which, in retrospect, makes alot of sense.

I now simply have 3 UIRefreshControllers, one for each tab

```
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"pull_to_refresh", nil)];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(refresh:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

self.refreshControl2 = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
self.refreshControl2.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"pull_to_refresh", nil)];
[self.refreshControl2 addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(refresh:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

self.refreshControl3 = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
self.refreshControl3.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"pull_to_refresh", nil)];
[self.refreshControl3 addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(refresh:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Which get added to their respective tabs when I initialize them

```
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xValue, 10, self.scrollView.frame.size.width-10,height)];
    tableView.tag = tabId;
    tableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
    tableView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
    switch(tabId){
        case 0:
            [tableView addSubview:self.refreshControl];
            break;
        case 1:
            [tableView addSubview:self.refreshControl2];
            break;
        case 2:
            [tableView addSubview:self.refreshControl3];
```

Case closed (finally).

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your `UIRefreshControl` on a `UIView` which is a subview of your `UITableView`:

```
UIView *refreshView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, table.frame.size.width, 44.0f)];
[table insertSubview:refreshView atIndex:0];

_refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[_refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[refreshView addSubview:_refreshControl];
```

Comment: the problem with that solution is that refreshviews may only be added to a UITable or its controller

Comment: The code snippet comes from a production app, so I'm not sure if I understand what you are saying. I create a `UIView`, add that as subview of my `UITableView` and add the `UIRefreshControl` to the `UIView`

Comment: strange... When I try your snippet it throws an exception:

'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UIRefreshControl may only be managed by a UITableViewController'